# SQL Server Cannot Update Table with Subqueries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update a temporary table called `@deletedRecords` which looks like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

With the data from a table called log that looks like this:

[image]

The `KeyValue` in the `log` table is the same as the `ID` in `@deletedRecords`.

There is a column in `@deletedRecords` for every FieldName for any particular key value.

I tried to extract the values using the following query:

```
UPDATE @deletedRecords
SET PatientName = (SELECT ACL.OldValue WHERE ACL.FieldName = 'CptCode'),
    ChargeNotes = (SELECT ACL.OldValue WHERE ACL.FieldName = 'ChargeNotes'),
    Units = (SELECT ACL.OldValue WHERE ACL.FieldName = 'Units'),
    ChargeStatusID = (SELECT ACL.OldValue WHERE ACL.FieldName = 'Units')
FROM Log ACL
JOIN @deletedRecords DR ON ACL.KeyValue = DR.ID
WHERE ACL.TableName = 'BillingCharge'
  AND ACL.EventType = 'DELETE'
```

However when I run the query all of the columns to be updated in `@deletedRecords` are null. Can somebody please help explain what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

In response to @Yogesh Sharma's answer, I elected to use the CTE method. I would this that using the values from the CTE to join to additional tables and extract their values during the update.

e.g. The `Log` table doesn't contain an old value for the `StatusName` but it does contain the `ChargeStatusID` which could be used to join to another table that contains that information such as this table `ChargeStatus`:

[image]

Thus I modified @Yogesh Sharma's code to the following:

```
WITH cte AS
...
UPDATE d 
       SET d.PatientName = c.PatientName
            , d.StatusName = cs.StatusName
FROM @deletedBillingChargeTemp d
JOIN cte c ON c.KeyValue = d.chargeID
JOIN ChargeStatus cs ON c.ChargeStatusID = cs.ChargeStatusID
```

However, once I add that secondary join, all of the updated values return to null as they were before @Yogesh Sharma's suggestions were implemented.

Comment: what field does the  ACL.KeyValue  correspond to?

Comment: It corresponds to the ID field in the @deletedRecords temp table

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not work because the UPDATE is executed multiple times for each row in DR, considering only the conditions specified in the last three rows of your query (not the ones specified in the subqueries). The values that remain in the table are the ones that correspond to the ACL row used in the last execution (and the order of execution cannot be controlled). If for ACL row used in the last execution the subqueries return NULL, you will get a NULL result.

See the example in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql topic, where it says "The results of an UPDATE statement are undefined if the statement includes a FROM clause that is not specified in such a way that only one value is available for each column occurrence that is updated, that is if the UPDATE statement is not deterministic.".

You should rewrite your query like this:

```
UPDATE @deletedRecords
SET PatientName = (
        SELECT ACL.OldValue FROM Log ACL 
        WHERE ACL.FieldName = 'CptCode' AND ACL.KeyValue = DR.ID
        AND ACL.TableName = 'BillingCharge' AND ACL.EventType = 'DELETE'
    ),
    ChargeNotes = (
        SELECT ACL.OldValue FROM Log ACL
        WHERE ACL.FieldName = 'ChargeNotes' AND ACL.KeyValue = DR.ID
        AND ACL.TableName = 'BillingCharge' AND ACL.EventType = 'DELETE'
    ),
    Units = (
        SELECT ACL.OldValue FROM Log ACL 
        WHERE ACL.FieldName = 'Units' AND ACL.KeyValue = DR.ID
        AND ACL.TableName = 'BillingCharge' AND ACL.EventType = 'DELETE'
    ),
    ChargeStatusID = (
        SELECT ACL.OldValue FROM Log ACL 
        WHERE ACL.FieldName = 'Units' AND ACL.KeyValue = DR.ID
        AND ACL.TableName = 'BillingCharge' AND ACL.EventType = 'DELETE'
    )
FROM @deletedRecords DR
```

Answer (score 0):

You would required to do some conditional aggregation for `log` table and do the `JOIN`s in order to update the temporary table `@deletedRecords` records

So, the conditional approach could be achieve via `CTE` or `Subquery`

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT KeyValue,
           MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'CptCode' THEN OldValue END) PatientName,
           MAX(CASE WHEN FieldName = 'ChargeNotes' THEN OldValue END) ChargeNotes, 
           ...
    FROM Log
    WHERE TableName = 'BillingCharge' AND EventType = 'DELETE'
    GROUP BY KeyValue 
)

UPDATE d 
       SET d.PatientName = c.PatientName,
           ... 
FROM @deletedRecords d
INNER JOIN cte c ON c.KeyValue = d.ID
```

The other way is to update your temporary table via `correlation`  approach

```
UPDATE d
       SET d.PatientName = (SELECT TOP 1 OldValue FROM Log WHERE KeyValue = d.ID AND 
             TableName = 'BillingCharge' AND EventType = 'DELETE' AND FieldName = 'CptCode'),
           d.ChargeNotes= (SELECT TOP 1 OldValue FROM Log WHERE KeyValue = d.ID AND 
             TableName = 'BillingCharge' AND EventType = 'DELETE' AND FieldName = 'ChargeNotes'),
            ...
FROM @deletedRecords d
```

Comment: Yogesh, both of these queries are working great thank you. I elected to use the cte method under the impression I would be able to join to multiple other tables and use their values in the update statement as well. When I attempt to do so, all of the columns return to NULL. See edited part of the question for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If your updated columns are `NULL`, these are it's possible causes:

- Since you are doing a `INNER JOIN`, records might not be joining correctly by their joining column. Make sure both tables have the same values on the joining columns.
- Since you are filtering in a `WHERE` clause, records might not fulfill your `TableName` and `EventType` filters. Make sure there are records that sucessfully `INNER JOIN` between them **and** they have the supplied `TableName` and `EventType`.
- The values you are asigning are `NULL`. Make sure your subqueries return a not null value.
- Table reference is off. When updating a table in SQL Server, always use the updating table alias if you are using one.

Use

```
UPDATE DR SET
    YourColumn = Value
FROM
    Log ACL
    JOIN @deletedRecords DR ON -...
```

Instead of

```
UPDATE @deletedRecords SET
    YourColumn = Value
FROM
    Log ACL
    JOIN @deletedRecords DR ON -...
```

- Make sure you are **NOT** checking the variable table values on another batch, script or procedure. Variable tables scope are limited to current batch or procedure, while temporary tables remain as long as the session is alive.
- Make sure that there isn't another statement that is setting those values as `NULL` after your update. Also keep an eye on your transactions (might not be commited or rolled back).